# Building a JavaScript Calculator from scratch?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am trying to build a JavaScript calculator from scratch, without following a tutorial, as a learning exercise. Much of the functionality is working, except if a calculation is performed right after another. ie:
7 x 6 + 42
In that case, it resets the display to 0 but seems to keep the variable anyways.

Is it necessary to store the numbers in 3 values, instead of 2? Currently I'm using:
-**currentValue**, which holds the previous total of the calculation.
-**newValue**, which is the number the user is currently entering.

```
function newNum(pressed) { //Adds digit of key pressed to new number being entered.
  //console.log ("Button pressed " + pressed);

  if (newValue == 0) { //If new calculation, newValue is set to key pressed.
    newValue += pressed;
  } else { //Else if continuing calculation, key pressed is added to end of newValue.
    newValue = newValue.toString();
    newValue = newValue + pressed; //Adds digit at end of String, then converts back to Number.
    newValue = parseFloat(newValue);
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = newValue;
}

function newCalc(pressed) { //Will use this mathematical operation to find the value.
  if (!currentValue) {
    currentValue = newValue;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = newValue;
  }

  newOperation = pressed;
  newValue = 0;
}

function equals() { //Resolves calculation.
  newValue = parseFloat(newValue);

  switch(newOperation) {
    case "/":
        currentValue = (currentValue / newValue);
        break;
    case "*":
        currentValue = (currentValue * newValue);
        break;
    case "-":
        currentValue = (currentValue - newValue);
        break;
    case "+":
        currentValue = (currentValue + newValue);
        break;
  }

  currentValue = parseFloat(currentValue);
  newValue = 0;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = currentValue;
}
```

https://codepen.io/adam_weiler/pen/aRNppX

I'm still learning and I know the code is a bit bloated. Any suggestions how to streamline it would be helpful too!

EDIT: I gave a bad example. I'm just coding a basic calculator, where you tap buttons to enter numbers. It doesn't use BEDMAS; the order of operations is "the order the user inputs them". So yeah, just a basic tapping calculator.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the code tries to calculate the 7*6 and the 6+42 at the same time, but there is no 6 which can be added to the 42 because it was multiplied by 7, so it can't be calculated with. You should make rules to the operation preference, when there is a multiplying or a dividing the sorrounding numbers should be calculated as the new number and then you can operate further with your adding or substracting. Also, you should define the left-to-right rule as well, so if you have 2*3/4 then the error won't occur again.

Comment: Expression parsing! What fun! I've done that a couple of times, but I wouldn't recommend it to a beginner...

Comment: Yea you are right, but operating with more than 2 number in a calculation at once also not for a beginner I think. At least I don't see how else could it be done with his method or at least with a method that is similar to his

Comment: I think he's trying to create a "classical" calculator. As in, when you press an operation or `=`, the previous operation gets resolved and you can't go back anymore. So pressing `2+2x2` would indeed yield 8.

Comment: Ohh, then I misunderstood the problem sorry! In that case whenever an operation sorrounded by 2 numbers and a new expression or the = is added, the first 2 number should be calculated and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you input

```
 7 | x | 8 | = | + | 5 | = |
```

it works without problems. I guess you want to execute `equals()` whenever an operation button is pressed, not only on `=`...

> Is it necessary to store the numbers in 3 values, instead of 2?

No you don't have to. The trick is to perform one operation after another so you always work with only two values:

```
 7
 7 x
 7 x 8
 7 x 8 +
 46 + // merged
 46 + 5
 46 + 5 =
 51 // merged
```

Comment: If I execute the equals() function each time a calculation button (+ - * /) then it will reset the newValue to 0. I think I'd have to change equals() function to realize that it needs to run the first time without a reset, then it can calculate/reset the following times.